# MongoDB - sort by subdocument match

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Say I have a `users` collection in MongoDB. A typical user document contains a name field, and an array of subdocuments, representing the user's characteristics. Say something like this:

```
{   
    "name": "Joey",
    "characteristics": [
        {
            "name": "shy",
            "score": 0.8
        },
        {
            "name": "funny",
            "score": 0.6
        },
        {
            "name": "loving",
            "score": 0.01
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I find the top X funniest users, sorted by how funny they are?

The only way I've found so far, was to use the aggregation framework, in a query similar to this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$project: {"_id": 1, "name": 1, "characteristics": 1, "_characteristics": '$characteristics'}},
    {$unwind: "$_characteristics"},
    {$match: {"_characteristics.name": "funny"}},
    {$sort: {"_characteristics.score": -1}},
    {$limit: 10}
]);
```

Which seems to be exactly what I want, except for the fact that according to [MongoDB's documentation on using indexes in pipelines](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes), once I call `$project` or `$unwind` in an aggregation pipeline, I can no longer utilize indexes to match or sort the collection, which renders this solution somewhat unfeasible for a very large collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are half way there. I would do

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {$match: { 'characteristics.name': 'funny' }},
  {$unwind: '$characteristics'},
  {$match: {'characteristics.name': 'funny'}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, name: 1, 'characteristics.score': 1}},
  {$sort: { 'characteristics.score': 1 }},
  {$limit: 10}
])
```

- I add a `match` stage to get rid of users without the `funny` attribute (which can be easily indexed).
- `unwind` and `match` again to keep only the certain part of the data
- keep only the necessary data with `project`
- `sort` by the correct score
- and `limit` the results.

that way you can use an index for the first match.

The way I see it, if the characteristics you are interested about are not too many, IMO it would be better to have your structure as

```
{  
    "name": "Joey",
    "shy": 0.8
    "funny": 0.6
    "loving": 0.01
}
```

That way you can use an index (sparse or not) to make your life easier!

Comment: Exactly what I ended up doing :) thanks for reaffirming it though. regarding the second suggestion - unfortunately there are simply too many different "characteristics" to index (MongoDB currently allows up to 64 different indexes per collection).